# TypeScript: Cannot import a type from a separate file in local dependency?

Tags: node.js, typescript, types, import, tsconfig

I have two local packages, `package1` and `package2`, and I want to use a TypeScript type `Car` declared in a separate file in and exported from `package1` in `package2`.

The structure of `package1` is:

```
package1/
  src/
    index.ts
    car.d.ts
  lib/
    index.d.ts // generated
  tsconfig.json
  package.json
```

`index.ts` from `package1` has only a single line:

```
export {Car} from './car';
```

So it's just re-exporting the type declared in `car.d.ts`, which may be something like

```
export interface Car {
  brand: string;
};
```

Now I want to use local package `package1` in local package `package2`. After running

```
npm i local/path/to/package1
```

I get the following structure for `package2`:

```
package2/
  src/
    index.ts
  lib/
  node_modules/
    package1/  // link to other package
  tsconfig.json
  packjage.json
```

Everything ok so far. `index.ts` from `package2` now tries to import `Car`:

```
import {Car} from './package1';
```

But that does not work; more precisely, `Car` is suddenly interpreted as a synonym to `any` (so typing does not work)! Even worse, I cannot compile `package2` because applying `tsc` to it gives me: `"error TS2307: Cannot find module './car' or its corresponding type declarations."`

My `tsconfig.json` for both packages is the following:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "strict": true,

    "removeComments": false,

    "sourceMap": true,
    "declarationMap": true,

    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,

    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "./lib"
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```